# perform frame transition using ffmpeg and php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

i am building a movie using various images using ffmpeg.

movie generating properly but what i want that. when any frame changes I want some effects to be perform like fade in, fade out, slide in , slide out, etc..

I want to perform this image changes from one to another i mean on frame changes.

any suggestion using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the frames with which you are creating the video, then it might be better to just learn how to create the tweening frames for these transitions.

There is a good thread on videohelp called, [Create your own movie titles/credits, transitions & effects in Linux.](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/306061-Create-your-own-movie-titles-credits-transitions-effects-in-Linux), that shows how you can use ImageMagick and bash to create the frames for the various effects you require.  The bash parts of the code could easily be performed in PHP instead.

Comment: //exec('/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/123712/domains/gr.projectbeta.biz/html/video/ffmpeg -r 0.1 -b 1800 -i /nfs/c08/h04/mnt/123712/domains/gr.projectbeta.biz/html/video/%d.jpg /nfs/c08/h04/mnt/123712/domains/gr.projectbeta.biz/html/video/new.mp4')   using this code to create a video using images

Comment: @Avinash: Yes, that is fine - just a matter of producing the visual effects within that image set at the right points, using image transitions.  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is like a command line photoshop.